# What is the auto generated <Script> tags inside .cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to learn C# ASP.NET and for that I'm building a project. I was wondering what the **Script** tags inside the .cshtml file is? For an instance every View page (Create, Edit, Delete etc.) has **Script** tags.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I see there is some jQuery included which is a library of JavaScript, but I don't see point of it being there.

**A little snippet of the code which is in the same file as the Script tag above:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Car</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean you're wondering what it is? Are you familiar with the web basics of HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: I just wanna know what the Script tags inside the .cshtml files is.

Comment: It’s for referencing JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> This script tag will call .js files for jquery and put into your html.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

**And you can add script tag in .cshtml There is to way for this**

**1.** Directly added script tag

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

> It's will be add this script under the RenderBody() method
>   (RenderBody() method is in the Layout.cshtml file)

**2.**
You have to add below code into your Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And you can add you can add your script into your View like this

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
```

then this script file will be added to where you put your @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) code.

> @RenderSection("Name", required: Boolean) code. 
>   Name: Type your name of whatever you want to call in .cshtml
>   Boolean: You can write true or false. If true you have to add this section into your every .cshtml file use this Layout.cshtml. Else you haven't.

Comment: I didn't understand much of your post. I'm just curious about what the purpose of the Script tag is inside the .cshtml file.

Comment: Because if you add your script into a Layout.cshtml will be call all your Views. But if you add in your Views will be call for just this. Sorry for my language and if I don't understand your question :(

Comment: Also this scripts add automatically in Layout.cshtml when you create a new project.